# Parent-Child relationship problem with mapstruct and hibernate when the child is changed

Tags: hibernate, orm, mapping, dto, mapstruct

In a REST API project using Jakarta JAX-RS, we use mapstruct to map DTO to Hibernate entities, and we are encountering a problem with parent-child relationships.

Let's call two classes Parent and Child, the first linked to the second.

When calling the API method to save the Parent, we do two things:

```
// find the entity in the database
Parent parent = parentRepo.findById(dto.id());
// update the entity with the dto's values
parentMapper.toDb(dto, parent);
```

Everything's fine except when the DTO changed the referenced child (i.e., the parent is not linked to the same child as before but to another one). Then Hibernate will instantly throw an Exception, as soon as the mapper tries to call the `setId()` method:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: identifier of an instance of ChildEntity was altered from 123 to 456
at org.hibernate.bytecode.enhance.spi.interceptor.EnhancementAsProxyLazinessInterceptor.handleWrite(EnhancementAsProxyLazinessInterceptor.java:265)
at org.hibernate.bytecode.enhance.spi.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.writeObject(AbstractInterceptor.java:157)
at com.acme.ChildEntity.$$_hibernate_write_id(ChildEntity.java)
at com.acme.BaseEntity.setId(BaseEntity.java:44)
at com.acme.ParentMapperImpl.resourceFileDtoToResourceFile(parentMapperImpl.java:272)
at com.acme.ParentMapperImpl.toDb(parentMapperImpl.java:210)
```

Hibernate's bytecode doesn't allow us to update the id to a new value, which makes sense.

The problem is that the mapper generated by mapstruct doesn't have any way to differentiate the two cases:

- case where the properties of the child are updated (the id stays the same, but the other properties are updated), in which case the Child should stay the same entity instance, with a few `setProperty()` called on it
- case where it's the parent-child relation itself which is updated (the id is different), in which case the Child should be another instance than the one previously returned by the database

Currently, the following mapper declaration...

```
ParentEntity toDb(ParentDto dtoParent, @MappingTarget ParentEntity dbParent);
```

... produces the following mapper implementation:

```
if ( dtoParent.child() != null ) {
    if ( dbParent.getChild() == null ) {
        dbParent.setChild( new ChildEntity() );
    }
    // this generated method calls every set() methods available
    childDtoToChildDb( dtoParent.child(), dbParent.getChild() );
}
else {
    dbParent.setChild( null );
}
```

It lacks something like:

```
// check if the child is the same or another one
if (dbParent.getChild().getId().equals(dtoParent.child().id()) { ... }
```

A possibility would be to tell the ParentMapper to always use a ChildMapper:

```
// declaration
@Mapper(... uses = {ChildMapper.class})
// implementation, replacing the whole previous if/else
dbParent.setChild( childMapper.toDb( dtoParent.child() ) );
```

In this case, the mapper always replace the child entity by a new one, but it challenges us to reattach the entity afterwards, and it seems to be prone to other caveats (the mapper is always creating a new Child entity, without regard to what is in the database).

I guess there is no way to handle everything from the generated mapper, as it should be able to call database in case of child's replacement, but maybe there is a way to customize mapstruct or to call its mapper in a smarter way. Maybe should we ask mapstruct to map only simple DTO to simple entities, and handle ourselves the entity-to-entity / DTO-to-DTO relationships?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the better way, but we found a way that seems successful, and I'm taking a few moments to write it down here if anyone needs it.

The basic idea is that the DTO should always update a true DB entity, updating only the fields it knows, overlaying only parts of the DB state contained in the Hibernate entity. Doing so, we can be sure that the entity is only modified in the DTO scope.

Doing otherwise could lead to problems, such as a brand new object only partially filled, a hVersion out of date, a conflict on the id as mentioned in the question.

To do it that way, we've got three parts:

**#1 An ObjectFactory for the mappers:**

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class AppMapperDatabaseHandler {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    /**
     * Loads database entity from any type from the DTO id.
     * EntityDto is just a contract with id() method.
     */
    @ObjectFactory
    public <E extends BaseEntity> E load(@TargetType @NotNull Class<E> type, @NotNull EntityDto dto) {
        return em.find(type, dto.id());
    }

    /**
     * Same as before, but if the entity is not in the database, uses a Supplier to produces the entity (should come from the business layer).
     * @DatabaseEntityMayBeNew is a custom annotation made to guide mapstruct to know which methods to use.
     */
    @ObjectFactory
    @DatabaseEntityMayBeNew
    public <E extends BaseEntity> E loadOrSupply(@TargetType @NotNull Class<E> type, @NotNull EntityDto dto, @NotNull Supplier<E> supplier) {
        E entity = em.find(type, dto.id());
        return entity != null ? entity : supplier.get();
    }

    /**
     * Merge/persist at the end of the mapping if entity can be new, to ensure it's not transient.
     */
    @AfterMapping
    @DatabaseEntityMayBeNew
    public <E extends BaseEntity> E merge(EntityDto dto, Supplier<E> producer, @MappingTarget E entity) {
        return em.merge(entity);
    }
}
```

**#2 A prototype definition in the MapperConfig:**

```
/**
 * Prototype to all "toDb" method, applying the DatabaseEntityMayBeNew qualifier when there is a supplier. This method is never called nor implemented by itself, it's just a mapstruct contract.
 */
@BeanMapping(qualifiedBy = DatabaseEntityMayBeNew.class)
BaseEntity genericToDb(EntityDto dto, Supplier<? extends BaseEntity> producer);
```

**#3 A couple of mapper methods for each DTO/DB pair:**

```
// case where the DTO can be mapped to a new entity
Parent toDb(ParentEditDto dto, Supplier<Parent> producer);

// case where the DTO is mapped to an already persisted entity
Parent toDb(ParentRightsDto dto);
```

Here two cases where those methods could be used:

```
// in a save REST method, where we use a business handler to create a new entity if needed
Parent parent = parentMapper.toDb(dto, () -> parentHandler.create());
// in another REST method, where the entity is already known
Parent parent = parentMapper.toDb(dto);
```

And, to show the results, here are the methods generated by mapstruct:

```
@Override
public Parent toDb(ParentEditDto dto, Supplier<Parent> producer) {
    // ... check params...
    Parent parent = appMapperDatabaseHandler.loadOrSupply( Parent.class, dto, producer );
    // ... call all set()...
    // as you can see, the child entity also uses a toDb() method
    parent.setChild( childMapper.toDb( dto.child() ) );
    // this method contains the following, same as here:
    // Child child = appMapperDatabaseHandler.load( Child.class, dto );
    Parent target = appMapperDatabaseHandler.merge( dto, producer, parent );
    // ...
}

@Override
public Parent toDb(ParentRightsDto dto) {
    // ... check params...
    Parent parent = appMapperDatabaseHandler.load( Parent.class, dto );
    // ... call all set()...
    // ...
}
```